# How to get the test step details from ExtentReport

Tags: extentreports

I have a automation suite which is using TestNG ExtentReport.. I need the same step to be updated in the test rail..

Is there anyway that we can extract the string value from ExtentTest to post in test rail as a comment..

Thanks,
Chandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the underlying domain to extract any information available to it:

```
test.getModel()
```

Comment: did not find any such method.. . i am not seeing that method.. i am seeing only getClass(), getDescription(), getTest(). getStartedTime(),getEndedTim(), getRunStatus()

Comment: I am using import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;

Comment: I am having extent report 2.41. May be this is new feature.. i will upgrade and test

Comment: @ChanGan for older versions, you can use test.getTest().

Comment: returning com.relevantcodes.extentreports.model.Test@7c7d3c46

Comment: @Anshoo List<Log> loggerDetails1 = logger.getTest().getLogList();.. but still i am unable to access

Comment: System.out.println(loggerDetails1.get(0).getDetails()); is working